# Unable to pass param from one test to other using ITestContext: returns null (TestNG + Java)

Tags: java, testng

I'm trying to pass param from one test to another using ITestContext:

```
public class One {
int waterfallId;

@Test()
public void testOne(ITestContext ctx) {
    /*here waterfallId was initialized*/
    ctx.setAttribute("waterfallId", waterfallId);
}

@Test()
public void testTwo(ItestContext ctx) {
    ctx.getAttribute("waterfallId"); //returns null
}

}
```

What's wrong? Any other ways to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Your testOne method should execute first and then testTwo method. If it is executed in an another way, you will get null as the value when you call getAttribute method.

To make sure, testOne is invoked before testTwo make a small change in the testTwo method like below.

```
@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"testOne"})
public void testTwo(ITestContext ctx) {
    System.out.println(ctx.getAttribute("waterfallId")); //returns null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

cxt.getAttribute("waterfallId"); //returns null
change this to 
ctx.getAttribute("waterfallId")

Answer (score 0):

it's ctx.getAttribute("waterfallId") not cxt.getAttribute("waterfallId")

Please refer to below snippet:

```
public class Test1{  
    int waterfallId;

    @Test()
    public void testOne(ITestContext ctx) {
        waterfallId=100;
        ctx.setAttribute("waterfallId", waterfallId);
    }

    @Test()
    public void testTwo(ITestContext ctx) {
        ctx.getAttribute("waterfallId"); 
        System.out.println(ctx.getAttribute("waterfallId"));
    }
}
```

Output : 100